# How to turn off the dotted line between lines in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, editor, appearance

I just downloaded the ADT from google which included the Juno version of Eclipse.

After making a project however, the default text editor has this horrible dashed / dotted line between every horizontal line. It's a pain to look at, but Eclipse's appearance preferences always leaves me completely lost.

Any ideas on how to turn off?

Screenshot :
[image: screenshot]
or link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOT8a.jpg

Comment: You might wish to take a screenshot, post it somewhere, and link to it from your question.

Comment: post the snapshot pls..not sure how exactly the lines look like in a text editor..

Answer (score 8):

I had the same dotted lines after choosing a darker color scheme in Eclipse and this fixed it:

```
Window/Preferences/General/Appearance/Jeeeyul's Themes/Edit/Underline Style: None
```

Comment: Robert ... Did you ever find a respectable `Dark' them for Eclipse that actually worked well? (Forget also Moonrise )

Answer (score 4):

You probably enabled "Show Whitespace Characters" by mistake.

Is this what you're asking to turn it off?

[image]

If so, just click at this button:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but it is NOT whitespace-- it is a fine dotted line between rows of text, between every line. Will try to post a pic somehow.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Jeeeyul theme
2. Goto `General > Appearance > Jeeeyul theme`
3. Select `Editor` tab and set `Underline Style` to `None`, as shown in the screenshot:

[image: See My Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

These dots represent white-spaces between words/lines.

You can turn them on/off by going to `Preference > General > Editors > Text Editors > Show Whitespace Characters`

I found this option in Eclipse Luna. Juno should also have similar option.

Edit:

Alternatively, as @Leandro suggested, there is a button in the toolbar to turn it on/off

Comment: it is NOT whitespace-- it is a fine dotted line between *rows* of text, between every line. Will try to post a pic somehow.